# How to store enum as string to database in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, enums

How do I create a migration in ruby where the default is a string rather than an Integer, I want to store enum into the database, but I do not want to store it as Integer, because then it does not make sense to another application that wants to use the same table. How do I do `default: "female"` instead of `default:0`

```
class AddSexToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :sex, :integer, default: 0
  end
end
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum sex: [:female, :male]
  has_secure_password
end
```

I

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: I am using sqlite for development and mysql for production

Answer (score 79):

Reading the [`enum`](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html) documentation, you can see *Rails* use the value index of the `Array` explained as:

> Note that when an Array is used, the implicit mapping from the values to database integers is derived from the order the values appear in the array.

But it is also stated that you can use a `Hash`:

> it's also possible to explicitly map the relation between attribute and database integer with a Hash.

With the example:

```
class Conversation < ActiveRecord::Base  
  enum status: { active: 0, archived: 1 }  
end
```

So I tested using *Rails 4.2.4* and *sqlite3* and created an `User` class with a `string` type for *sex* type and a `Hash` in the `enum` with `string` values(I am using *fem* and *mal* values to differ from *female* and *male*):

Migration:

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :sex, default: 'fem'
    end
  end
end
```

Model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum sex: { female: 'fem', male: 'mal' }
end
```

And in console:

```
u = User.new
#=>  #<User id: nil, sex: "fem">
u.male?
#=> false
u.female?
#=> true
u.sex
#=> "female"
u[:sex]
#=> "fem"
u.male!
# INSERT transaction...
u.sex
#=> "male"
u[:sex]
#=> "mal"
```

Comment: so in the db is stored `fem`?

Comment: @ArnoldRoa Yes, `fem` id DB, can be set on the field as `female`.

Comment: Very nice explanation and walkthrough, with references to official docs.  This is a great example of a qulity SO answer!  Thank you!

Answer (score 52):

I normally do the following:

```rb
# in the migration in db/migrate/…
def self.up
  add_column :works, :status, :string, null: false, default: 'offering'
end

# in app/models/work.rb
class Work < ApplicationRecord
  ALL_STATES = %w[canceled offering running payment rating done].freeze

  enum status: ALL_STATES.zip(ALL_STATES).to_h
end
```

By using a hash as argument for `enum` ([see docs](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html)) this stores strings in the database. At the same time this still allows you to use all the cool Rails helper methods:

```
w = Work.new
#=>  #<Work id: nil, status: "offering">
w.rating?
#=> false
w.offering?
#=> true
w.status
#=> "offering"
w[:status]
#=> "offering"
w.done!
# INSERT transaction...
w.status
#=> "done"
w[:status]
#=> "done"
```

**Update for one-liner:**

I overlooked completely we've got [`index_by`](https://apidock.com/rails/v1.2.6/Enumerable/index_by) since Rails 1.2.6. This makes the solution a one-liner even:

```rb
enum status: %w[canceled offering running payment rating done].index_by(&:to_sym)
```

Alternatively we've got [`index_with`](https://apidock.com/rails/v6.0.0/Enumerable/index_with) since Rails 6.0.0:

```rb
enum status: %i[canceled offering running payment rating done].index_with(&:to_s)
```

Comment: It seems the doc doesn't have anything to hint storing enum value as string. Are you sure it's stored as string, not integer?

Comment: @Anwar yes, it stores as a string if you give it a try yourself. This can be seen with the above `w[:status]` which, in a normal rails enum would return a string.

Comment: Oh, that's where @coorasse gets "his" ideas then 

Answer (score 20):

[`enum`](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html) in Rails and [`ENUM` type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/enum.html) in MySQL are 2 different things.

1. `enum` in Rails is just a wrapper around your `integer` column so it's easier for you to use strings in queries, rather than integers. But on database level it's all converted to integers (automatically by Rails), since that's the type of the column.
2. `ENUM` type in MySQL is vendor-specific column type (for example, SQLite [doesn't support it](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html), but [PostgreSQL does](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-enum.html)). In MySQL :

> An ENUM is a string object with a value chosen from a list of permitted values that are enumerated explicitly in the column specification at table creation time.

```
CREATE TABLE shirts (
    name VARCHAR(40),
    size ENUM('x-small', 'small', 'medium', 'large', 'x-large')
);
INSERT INTO shirts (name, size) VALUES ('dress shirt','large'), ('t-shirt','medium'),
  ('polo shirt','small');
SELECT name, size FROM shirts WHERE size = 'medium';
+---------+--------+
| name    | size   |
+---------+--------+
| t-shirt | medium |
+---------+--------+
```

For the migration, you need to do this:

```
class AddSexToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :sex, "ENUM('female', 'male') DEFAULT 'female'"
  end
end
```

Comment: If you go this route you need to switch to SQL schema dumps, otherwise Rails will put a string column type in your schema.rb file. Switch with the following in config/application.rb:

`config.active_record.schema_format = :sql`

Comment: Is the comment about "you need to switch to SQL schema dumps" still accurate? I have a Rails 6.0.3.3 project using MySQL (mysql gem v0.5.3) and `t.column  :foo, "enum('bar')"` in a migration generates `t.column  "foo", "enum('bar')"` in the schema.rb, not a string column.

Answer (score 0):

There's steps to add enum as string to model `Company`

```bash
bin/rails g migration AddStatusToCompanies status
```

```rb
class AddStatusToCompanies < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
  def change
    add_column :companies, :status, :string, null: false, default: 'claimed'
    add_index  :companies, :status
  end
end
```

```bash
bin/rails db:migrate
```

- Values are strings (symbols not working)
- add Default
- add Prefix

```rb
enum status: {
  claimed: 'claimed',
  unverified: 'unverified',
  verified: 'verified',
}, default: 'claimed'
```

- Add validation (or will raise sql exception)

```rb
validates :status, inclusion: { in: statuses.keys }, allow_nil: true
```

Answer (score -1):

To my knowledge it is not possible with standard Rails enum. Look at https://github.com/lwe/simple_enum, it is more functionally rich, and also allows storing of enum values as strings to DB (column type string, i.e. varchar in terms of DB).