# Enum with plus or - sign doesn't work with ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have the following model:

```
class Visitor < ApplicationRecord
  enum timezone: {
    'UTC': 'UTC',
    'UTC-12': 'UTC-12',
    'UTC-11': 'UTC-11',
    'UTC-10': 'UTC-10',
    'UTC-9': 'UTC-9',
    'UTC-8': 'UTC-8',
    'UTC-7': 'UTC-7',
    'UTC-6': 'UTC-6',
    'UTC-5': 'UTC-5',
    'UTC-4': 'UTC-4',
    'UTC-3': 'UTC-3',
    'UTC-2': 'UTC-2',
    'UTC-1': 'UTC-1',
    'UTC+0': 'UTC+0',
    'UTC+1': 'UTC+1',
    'UTC+2': 'UTC+2',
    'UTC+3': 'UTC+3',
    'UTC+4': 'UTC+4',
    'UTC+5': 'UTC+5',
    'UTC+6': 'UTC+6',
    'UTC+7': 'UTC+7',
    'UTC+8': 'UTC+8',
    'UTC+9': 'UTC+9',
    'UTC+10': 'UTC+10',
    'UTC+11': 'UTC+11',
    'UTC+12': 'UTC+12',
    'UTC+13': 'UTC+13',
    'UTC+14': 'UTC+14'
  }, _suffix: true
end
```

When I try to create a new visitor with any timezone that contains `-` or `+`, it won't work:

```
visitor = Visitor.create(timezone: 'UTC-10')
visitor.errors
=> => #<ActiveModel::Errors:0x0000561b5de92338 @base=#<Visitor id: nil, ipv4: nil, ipv6: nil, timezone: "UTC-1", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>, @messages={:timezone=>["is an invalid timezone"]}, @details={:timezone=>[{:error=>:inclusion, :value=>"UTC-10"}]}>
```

and if I send an invalid one, it will raise an error (which makes sense):

```
ArgumentError ('UTC-100' is not a valid timezone)
```

Does anyone know if it's not possible to use enums with `-` or `+`?

Thank you.

Comment: You could check out hstore maybe.

Answer (score 1):

As of Rails documentation: `Declare an enum attribute where the values map to integers in the database`

You are trying to map strings in your enum `timezone`, you should change to:

```rb
class Visitor < ApplicationRecord
  enum timezone: {
    'UTC': 100, # duplicate of 'UTC+0'
    'UTC-12': -12,
    'UTC-11': -11,
    'UTC-10': -10,
    'UTC-9': -9,
    'UTC-8': -8,
    'UTC-7': -7,
    'UTC-6': -6,
    'UTC-5': -5,
    'UTC-4': -4,
    'UTC-3': -3,
    'UTC-2': -2,
    'UTC-1': -1,
    'UTC+0': 0,
    'UTC+1': 1,
    'UTC+2': 2,
    'UTC+3': 3,
    'UTC+4': 4,
    'UTC+5': 5,
    'UTC+6': 6,
    'UTC+7': 7,
    'UTC+8': 8,
    'UTC+9': 9,
    'UTC+10': 10,
    'UTC+11': 11,
    'UTC+12': 12,
    'UTC+13': 13,
    'UTC+14': 14
  }, _suffix: true
end
```

I suggest you remove `UTC` in favor of `UTC+0` (or the opposite) because they mean the same timezone.

Comment: TIL that `UTC+14` exists. Thanks!

Comment: That's not really the problem... I can map strings to strings, specially if I'm actually enum in the table column. The problem is related with the symbols (`+` and `-`).

Comment: Please provide us with the schema of your database

Comment: Did you follow any step similar to this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32938729/how-to-store-enum-as-string-to-database-in-rails